# Remove line-breaks after block tags with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to remove the line-breaks after **block** tags such as `h1, h2, ul, blockquote` etc. before converting them to PDF.

I am currently using `string.Replace` method as below. Is there a better solution with `RegEx`?

```
text = text.Replace("center]\r\n", "center]")
            .Replace("li]\r\n", "li]")
            .Replace("ol]\r\n", "ol]")
            .Replace("ul]\r\n", "ul]")
            .Replace("center]\n", "center]")
            .Replace("li]\n", "li]")
            .Replace("ol]\n", "ol]")
            .Replace("ul]\n", "ul]")

            .Replace("h1]\r\n", "h1]")
            .Replace("h2]\r\n", "h2]")
            .Replace("h3]\r\n", "h3]")
            .Replace("h4]\r\n", "h4]")
            .Replace("h1]\n", "h1]")
            .Replace("h2]\n", "h2]")
            .Replace("h3]\n", "h3]")
            .Replace("h4]\n", "h4]")

            .Replace("\r\n[h1]", "[h1]")
            .Replace("\r\n[h2]", "[h2]")
            .Replace("\r\n[h3]", "[h3]")
            .Replace("\r\n[h4]", "[h4]")
            .Replace("\n[h1]", "[h1]")
            .Replace("\n[h2]", "[h2]")
            .Replace("\n[h3]", "[h3]")
            .Replace("\n[h4]", "[h4]")
            ;
```

**NOTE THAT**

This is just one step of the process. There are many other custom tags such as `blue, red, email doc` which are already being parsed into HTML. There reason I am trying to remove line breaks is because I cannot use the line-break `br` tag. We must maintain the normal line-breaks in the text document.

Comment: You appear to be parsing HTML.  You should know that HTML is not a regular language, therefore regular expressions are not the best choice.  Please consider [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: This is hardly a case of "parsing HTML". He's simply looking for tags. That's it.

Comment: @icemanind You say it's simple, but it's not.  It's quite possible for the HTML code to have string literals that are HTML tags that shouldn't be treated as HTML tags.  You can have HTML tags in string literals in javascript code, for example, and they presumably need to be treated differently than *actual* HTML tags.  Looking for HTML tags in an HTML file just isn't a simple problem, certainly not one that would be well suited to regex or basic string find/replace operations.

Comment: @Servy - I'm looking at his existing code though, which apparently works. His existing code doesn't seem to indicate there would be any string literals with tags or javascript code. It looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: @icemanind He says that he's running the code against arbitrary HTML code.  That means his current code doesn't work.  He may have tried it out on a few fairly simple cases, and it may have worked, but it won't work on lots of other types of valid HTML files.  It looks straightforward *if you ignore all sorts of possible valid HTML files*.  If you restrict the problem to a subset of HTML that can be easily processed, with no scripts, and other difficult to process items, then sure, it's an easy problem.  There is no such restriction here though.

Answer (score 0):

How about the regx

```
((?:center|li|[ou]l|h[1-4])\])\r?\n|\r?\n(\[h[1-4]\])
```

replace with the contents of capture group 1

```
text = text.Replace("((?:center|li|[ou]l|h[1-4])\\])\\r?\\n|\\r?\\n(\\[h[1-4]\\])", "$1")
```

Comment: The regex constant doesn't work. It says bad compile constant.

Comment: @SoniAli you need to escape `\n` as `\\n` so for `\r`. I have edited the answer